# Getting ERROR: [Errno 60] Operation timed out on Google Function Creation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, python-3.7

Getting bellow error while creating Google Function with Gcloud Command.

> ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) [Errno 60] Operation timed out

I am using the below command to create the function from my local machine.

```
gcloud functions deploy hello_get --region=us-central1 --service-account=project-name@appspot.gserviceaccount.com --memory=2048MB --runtime python37 --trigger-http --allow-unauthenticated --verbosity=info --entry-point=helloworld
```

Comment: This can happen if you have a big latency to the region that you deploying your function to, have you tried deploying you function to a region closer to your local machine? [Here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/locations) is a list of all the locations available